# Manga/manhwa where the main character was schooled by a dragon lady

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, manga

All I can really remember is that it had that unpolished comic style where the line art wasn't as clean as a professionally done manga/manhwa and I think it was in color.

Storywise all I really recall is that the main character was pretty strong and something happened to make him go look for his mentor dragon, who just happens to be able to turn herself into a woman and I think they had an intimate relationship in the past. She teases him a lot in front of the people he was leading around at the time.

I vaguely recall some world ending stuff was going on around the time which is why he went looking for her.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is [*4 cut hero*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=124028).

> The Hero has defeated the Demon King, but the Princess he meant to save turned out to be a Prince. NEETdom, here he comes, but a life of relaxation surrounded by animes is a pretty sweet deal.
>
> Unfortunately, he gets caught up in millennia old legends, curses, and a twisted plot involving multiple Kingdoms and many dragons. Through and through, though, he'll follow a path of whimsy, even if that involves him palling it up with "villains".

The starting point isn't right. But in the middle he shows that his mentor was a dragon loli (the dragon chose this form). The MC is strong, capable of defeating the demon king.

They had a somewhat love relationship. When he cut her horn, she flushed. He chose to find his mentor but not because of the world ending, but because his life is threatened.